# How do I recursively create symbolic links for jpgs and save the link in a relative directory?

Tags: batch-file, symlink

I'm really unfamiliar with batch file creation. 
The scenario is I'm saving podcast episodes in folders arranged by the podcast title. - and I'm storing jpegs of the podcast covers on a different drive, arranged by the podcast title. So, I have...

(Let's say [Podcast Title] = The No Sleep Podcast)

```
D:\Podcast Covers\[Podcast Title]\[Podcast Title].jpg
```

and

```
E:\Podcasts\Episodes\[Podcast Title]\[Episode_title].mp3
```

I'd like to create a batch file that will loop through the `Podcast Covers` - folder and create a symbolic link for each of the jpeg covers >> saving it as

```
E:\Podcasts\Episodes\[Podcast Title]\[Podcast Title].jpg
```

---

**Note**: I already know how to create a single symbolic link with a batch file

```
mklink "E:\Podcasts\Episodes\[Podcast Title]\[Podcast Title].jpg" "D:\Podcast Covers\[Podcast Title]\[Podcast Title].jpg"
```

and save it as a .bat file

Comment: Could handle file management in code then avoid having to deal with symlinks

Comment: See `help mklink` in an open cmd window or visit [ss64.com/nt/mklink.html](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html)

Comment: @ScottStensland - not sure I understand. I want to create a symlink instead of duplicating the jpeg file.  I just like to store all my images on one drive and all mp3's on a different drive.

Comment: @LotPings Thanks; I appreciate the link. I know how to create an mklink and have a batch file that does that. But, I don't know how to create a batch file that will create links based on variables.  - read my question again.

Comment: @StackJohan `*`(asterisk) is a wildcard for many commands. string `A*` could mean `AB`, `AA`, `ABC`, etc....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Echo off
For /d %%A in ("D:\Podcast Covers\*"
) do If exist "%%A\%%~nA.jpg" ^
     If exist "E:\Podcasts\Episodes\%%~nA\" ^
echo mklink   "E:\Podcasts\Episodes\%%~nA\%%~nA.jpg" ^
              "%%A\%%~nA.jpg"
```

If the output looks OK remove the echo in front of mklink.

To understand the batch you may have to read the following references:
http://ss64.com/nt/for.html
http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html

Comment: Thanks! That works perfectly! - and I was able to create another, similar batch file using the references you provided. :)